# how to get Intersection of two query in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table that has two column with two foreign key from two different table.

this is my relation table:

[image: table]

I want to select those student who can speak both language with id 3 and 4.

How can i wrote a query to give me for e.x 12 , 14

Answer (score 5):

You can give it a try:

```
SELECT 
 student_id,
 COUNT(*) total
FROM your_table 
WHERE language_id IN (3,4)
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

---

Only `IN` doesn't ensure that a student is involved both in language id `3 & 4`.

You need to use `GROUP BY student_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` in order to ensure those `student_id`s to be in the result who were involved both in `language id 3 & 4`

---

Another solution would be using `INNER JOIN`. But it doesn't scale.

```
SELECT 
A.student_id 
FROM your_table A 
INNER JOIN your_table B ON A.student_id = B.student_id 
  AND A.language_id = 3 AND B.language_id = 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Assume your relation is named "my-relation":

```
 SELECT R1.student_Id FROM my-Relation R1 join my-Relation R2 on R1.student_id = R2.student_id where R1.language_Id = '3' and R2.language_id = '4'
```